# How do I get polyfills to work with Relay?

Tags: relayjs

I have a PHP app and I'm trying to use it with GraphQL and Relay, but trying to get Relay working I keep getting this error in my Browser (Chrome and Safari)

> warning.js:36 Warning: Relay relies on polyfills for ES6 features in older browsers. Babel provides a good one: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

I've tried all sorts of things, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Change webpack configuration, include the `polyfill.js` as a script.

I can't ignore that warning, because later on I will get:

> RelayTaskQueue.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: _promise2.default is not a constructor

Comment: Any luck on this? I've been having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem myself. The problem was that I was running on Mac OS X with a case **insensitive** file system.

I tried creating a disk image with case sensitivity, and it worked.  Followed instructions here. https://gist.github.com/dixson3/8360571 #